# send mail in laravel 4.2

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to send my mail using laravel 4.2, but it's not working.

Ther's my mail configuration:

```
<?php

return array(

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Mail Driver
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Laravel supports both SMTP and PHP's 'mail' function as drivers for the
    | sending of e-mail. You may specify which one you're using throughout
    | your application here. By default, Laravel is setup for SMTP mail.
    |
    | Supported: 'smtp', 'mail', 'sendmail', 'mailgun', 'mandrill', 'log'
    |
    */

    'driver' => 'mail',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | SMTP Host Address
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may provide the host address of the SMTP server used by your
    | applications. A default option is provided that is compatible with
    | the Mailgun mail service which will provide reliable deliveries.
    |
    */

    'host' => 'localhost',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | SMTP Host Port
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This is the SMTP port used by your application to deliver e-mails to
    | users of the application. Like the host we have set this value to
    | stay compatible with the Mailgun e-mail application by default.
    |
    */

    'port' => 587,

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Global 'From' Address
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | You may wish for all e-mails sent by your application to be sent from
    | the same address. Here, you may specify a name and address that is
    | used globally for all e-mails that are sent by your application.
    |
    */

    'from' => array('address' => 'noreply@test.cab', 'name' => 'tes'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | E-Mail Encryption Protocol
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may specify the encryption protocol that should be used when
    | the application send e-mail messages. A sensible default using the
    | transport layer security protocol should provide great security.
    |
    */

    'encryption' => 'tls',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | SMTP Server Username
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | If your SMTP server requires a username for authentication, you should
    | set it here. This will get used to authenticate with your server on
    | connection. You may also set the 'password' value below this one.
    |
    */

    'username' => '',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | SMTP Server Password
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may set the password required by your SMTP server to send out
    | messages from your application. This will be given to the server on
    | connection so that the application will be able to send messages.
    |
    */

    'password' => '',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Sendmail System Path
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | When using the 'sendmail' driver to send e-mails, we will need to know
    | the path to where Sendmail lives on this server. A default path has
    | been provided here, which will work well on most of your systems.
    |
    */

    'sendmail' => '/usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Mail 'Pretend'
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | When this option is enabled, e-mail will not actually be sent over the
    | web and will instead be written to your application's logs files so
    | you may inspect the message. This is great for local development.
    |
    */

    'pretend' => false,

);
```

and my calling the function in another controller

```
try {

                Mail::send('emails.email_walker_new_register', array('mail_body' => $message_body), function ($message) use ($email, $subject) {
                    $message->to($email)->subject($subject);
                });
            } catch (Services_Twilio_RestException $e) {

                Log::error($e->getMessage());
            }
```

Comment: Show the error.

Comment: Given you catch the Exception and you log the message, have a look at the error log.

Comment: "_it's not working_" Is that the error message you get?

Comment: Lol, the question has been edited. In the first version he said that no error is shown, that's why I told him to check the log.

Comment: can your server send email? it might not be a laravel issue

Comment: mail can be sent from webmail